# Unity: игрок почему-то проходит сквозь твердые объекты

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть игрок с компонентами: `Rigidbody2d` и `2d box collider`, а также есть с такими же компонентами ящики. У меня почему-то игрок проходит сквозь ящики, но такого не должно быть.
Скрин с настройками компонентов игрока: http://joxi.ru/4AkvDWEFypp0M2
Скрипт передвижения игрока:

```
void FixedUpdate() 
{ 
if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal")) MoveHorizontal(); 
if (Input.GetButton("Vertical")) MoveVertical(); 
} 

private void MoveHorizontal() 
{ 
Vector3 direction = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); 
if (transform.position.x + direction.x < 9 && transform.position.x + direction.x > -9) 
{ 
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, transform.position + direction, speed * Time.deltaTime); 
} 

} 
private void MoveVertical() 
{ 
Vector3 direction = transform.up * Input.GetAxis("Vertical"); 
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, transform.position + direction, speed * Time.deltaTime); 
}
```

Особенность: если ящик стоит на месте, то через него не получается пройти, а если ящик двигается - то игрок проходит сквозь (не сразу, но проходит)

Скрипт движения ящика:

```
void FixedUpdate () {      
    position.x -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = position;
}
```

Comment: проблема, может и не полностью, но хотя бы частично, заключается в том, что вы используете физику, но персонажа двигаете через transform напрямую (движение которое игнорирует физику). Используйте методы движения связанные с приложением сил к Rigitbody

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать. Какой наиболее лёгкий способ передвигать с помощью физики?

Comment: вам в сторону Rigitbody.AddForce

Comment: Его уже нет :( Буду искать другие варианты, спасибо за ответ

Comment: попробовал перемещать через transform.Translate, но все равно игрок проходит сквозь ящики

Comment: может быть из-за того что они на разных координатах по Z? Но игра то у меня все равно двумерная

Comment: transform.Translate это тоже перемещение в обход физики

Comment: попробовал через rigidbody.MovePosition - заработало, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как правильно заметил Виталий, надо двигать объекты через физику, а не перемещать его мгновенно. Для этого наиболее удобно будет подходить [Rigidbody2D.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html). Делаете все то же самое только изменяете позицию не напрямую в трансформ, а говорите ригидбоди чтобы он изменял позицию. Есть подобный метод и для вращения.